# JavaFX Platform.runlater doesn't update gui sometimes

Tags: multithreading, listview, javafx

```
    clientList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
        if(newSelection!=null){
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    conversationText.positionCaret(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                }
            });
            }
    });
```

So I have this code that needs to scroll bottom for each conversation(from GUI) when the user is selected. There is a tableview that contains User objects and each user has a different textarea(which is conversationtext here) and it gets updated when you click on a user row, but the scrolling part won't work occasionally, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and I couldn't find a pattern behind it if there is any.

Can someone explain why sometimes the scrolling will work and sometimes it won't and if there is any fix to this, the reason behind this etc.

Comment: Not sure how to answer the question, but 1. have you tried `conversationText.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE);`, which is the property design to control the scroll position? And 2. why are you using `Platform.runLater(...)` here? The listener will be invoked on the FX Application Thread anyway.

Comment: @James_D I just tried but no luck with that either, if there was a problem with the positionCaret method it would never work, and what is strange with this situation is sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, and if i don't use Platform.runlater i don't get any errors but the scrolling never happens.

Comment: Seems to make a difference whether this happens before or after the next layout pulse. `Platform.runLater` doesn't guaranty that it runs after the next layout pulse though...